# How to change TabLayout background programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

What i am doing is I am trying to change `Toolbar`, `StatusBar` and `Tablayout` color other than the default `theme` color pragmatically , i am able to successfully change the color of all `widgets` but getting some type of boundary of app theme's primary color in `Tablayout` don't know why ? can anyone tell me how to remove it ? Is any default style for it is defined as edges of `Tablayout` are also not rectangular.

Screen :

[image: here green color visible at boundaries of Tablayout is the apps theme color]

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/app_bar_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".mainFlow.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: use `app:tabBackground="@drawable/colorPrimaryDark"`

Comment: @Wizard i want to change background color programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Your xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    ....
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
    ...
    />
```

and the selector
res/drawable/tab_color_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

Or programmatically:

```
tabLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
```

Comment: i want to change background color programmatically can you tell me how is it possible

Comment: try this: `tabLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.tab_color_selector));` @kapil-rajput

Comment: It has worked for me..Why is it downvoted, +1 from my side.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I wanted to change the entire tablayout not only the tab selected because I am using it with day/night mode. I solved it by checking the boolean that I have set for night theme prior to setting the content view in onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences nightModeSwitchState = getSharedPreferences("NightModeSwitchState", 0);
    mNightModeSwitchState = nightModeSwitchState.getBoolean("NightModeSwitchState", false);

    if (mNightModeSwitchState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_night);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
    }
```

I have two layouts made both include tabLayouts. One of them references a style file for tabLayout set to night mode colors with the dark background and the layout references a style file set to regular colors for the tablayout.

```
<style name="CategoryTab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CategoryTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_regular_theme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="CategoryTabNight" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CategoryTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_layout_dark_mode</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

The style files reference different drawables that control the background colors as you can see above.. and here are the drawables...

Here is night mode drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/dark_grey" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/dark_grey"/>
</selector>
```

Here is regular mode drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/app_bar" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/app_bar"/>
</selector>
```

Everything else is the layouts are identical as not to mess anything up just the style files for the tablayouts are changed. I hope this makes sense. I tested it and it works for me. I have tried so many other things and nothing worked. It is important to call Shared Preference to get the value before checking the boolean. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've set tabs background color as transparent:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

and then I just set TabLayout background color in code:

```
tabs.setBackgroundColor()
```

Comment: The background color setting worked programmatically when the color was set as transparent in xml. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Code in Kotlin

First of all, we will create CustomTabLayout

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

class CustomTabLayout : TabLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    )

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    }
}
```

Then we will use it directly in the layout file

```
<com.packagename.CustomTabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab"
                        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
                        app:tabIndicator="@null"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                        app:tabBackground="@null"
                        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:layout_height="40dp" />
```

And it will work tab layout with transparent background.

You can change color according to your requirement in customTablayout class.

Comment: You appear to have posted multiple identical answers recently. If the questions are the same, you should flag them as duplicates. If they're different, then you should tailor your answers to each question. Identical answers are liable to be deleted.